# IntelliJ: Strange gaps before Java annotations

Tags: intellij-idea

I updated to IntelliJ 2022.1 and it shows gaps before every java annotation (between line 78 and 79) :

[image]

It did not do this in the previous version I used (2021.3) and I want to deactivate it, but I can't find anything in the settings. So far I searched for: gap, height, lines, ...

Does anyone know how to deactivate this?

Comment: Try to add `editor.codeVision.new=false` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. If you post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291945 .

As a workaround, you can add `editor.codeVision.new=false` in `Help | Edit Custom Properties` and restart the IDE.

Comment: A better way to disable it is to use settings Preferences | Editor | Inlay Hints, Code VIsion group

Answer (score 2):

Disable the inlay hints in settings -> editor -> inlay hints